# Как связать SVG и Google Таблицы

Tags: svg, google-spreadsheet, таблицы

Есть SVG файл, такие делаются в SolidWorks Composer, также из SW можно выгрузить спецификацию в EXCEL или Google Таблицы, вопрос как отметкой флажка в, например гугл таблицах автоматом закрасить позицию в спецификации и элемент на картинке?

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gJP3aAG7TQSJz3mDPKgccXPsbRleY00a?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

В целом, такая задача выполнима, если использовать [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service) для отображения SVG, а сами данные из файла SVG импортировать на лист таблицы Google в виде рядов с чек-боксами, названиями деталей, их идентификаторами. В ходе импорта можно использовать регулярные выражения.

Скрипт на стороне клиента (то есть там, где SVG) при помощи метода [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) будет регулярно запрашивать информацию о состоянии чек-боксов на листе и при необходимости менять свойства перекрашиваемых элементов. В приведенном примере файла SVG присутствуют все необходимые для этого идентификаторы элементов.

К сожалению, полная реализация задачи в коде достаточно трудоёмка и заняла бы здесь слишком много места, поэтому в ответе на вопрос приходится давать лишь общие рекомендации. Кроме того, не совсем ясно, как именно будет использовано решение на практике, что уже выходит за рамки обсуждения.